# setTimeout and scope in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm playing around with setTimeout, and I'm not getting the results I'd expect. I have an array by the name of cars, and I have a function called fetchCars which simply calls setTimeout and returns the cars after 1000 ms. As far as I know the setTimeout should have access to the cars array because of closures, but for some reason when I an await an invocation of fetchCars I don't get any results.

Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-pasteur-xjzgo?file=/src/index.js)
Here is my code:

```
const cars = [
  { brand: "Toyota", model: "Camry", year: "2014" },
  { brand: "BMW", year: "2016", model: "M3" },
  { brand: "Porche", model: "911", year: "2018" }
];
export const fetchCars = async () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    return cars;
  }, 1000);
};

const recieveCars = async () => {
  const cars = await fetchCars();
  console.log(cars);
};
recieveCars();


///Console Output:  undefined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're seeing `undefined` in your console is that `fetchCars` returns a Promise (only by virtue that you have tagged it with `async`) that resolves to undefined - in other words, it doesn't really return anything!

```
export const fetchCars = async () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    // the callback you have passed to setTimeout will return cars, not the fetchCars function
    return cars;
  }, 1000);
};
```

If you want `fetchCars` to return a value, it needs to return a Promise that will resolve to the value you want to return.

```
// no need for async here, because we're going to be returning a Promise explicilty
export const fetchCars = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(cars);
    }, 1000);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` uses a callback and has no native `Promise` version. While Brendan's answer is correct and perfectly functional, another option that is more consistent with `async/await` style is to `await` the timeout promise in the `async` function, then return the value.

```js
export const fetchCars = async () => {
  await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 1000);

  return cars;
};
```

If you're doing this a lot, a convenience function like this:

```js
const delay = (delayTime) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, delayTime));
```

Will then let you write your function like:

```js
export const fetchCars = async () => {
  await delay(1000);

  return cars;
};
```

Comment: "`setTimeout`[...] has no native `Promise` version.", [it's coming](https://github.com/WICG/scheduling-apis/blob/main/explainers/prioritized-post-task.md#posting-delayed-tasks).